# Use of unresolved identifier 'STPCardParams' in swift 4.0

Tags: ios, stripe-payments, swift4

I am trying to integrate Stripe in my application. But when I am trying to implement Custom Card form, it's giving me this error - `Use of unresolved identifier 'STPCardParams'`

Here is the following details:

Deployment target: 10.0

Stripe version: 11.4.0

In AppDelegate:
[image]

Now having this issue:
[image]

[image]

Any Solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the issue by following steps -

1. Remove 'Stripe'.
2. Delete derived data.
3. Restart Xcode.
4. Again add 'Stripe' pod.
5. Simply import 'Stripe' module in `AppDelegate` and my `Payment View Controller`.

Now it's working.
Weird issue.